# Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_17f0_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)

Tags: mysql, php

In site after logged in it is redirecting me to `profile.php` but on that page it shows me error like this:

> Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_17f0_0.MYD' (Errcode: 17)

Actually I don't know what this error is and why its given.

Comment: write permission on `/tmp` for PHP? disk out of space? ...

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? in the browser via a PHP page? if so, please post the code minus any sensitive information contained in it.

Comment: @rabuddle but i dont find the tmp folder in my server

Comment: @Nexerus it is coming on server in php page , and i don't find the tmp folder in my server

Comment: @user900324 Perhaps that's the problem. There should be a /tmp/ folder. (or you'll have to configure mysql to use another temporary folder - this error seems to come from MySQL).

Comment: @nos The errnos that PHP reports for MySQL generally start at 1000, provided it's not an error MySQL encountered during a syscall such as open() / write() in which it just reports the system errno. 17 is actually 'file exists', which is why I find this very strange.

Comment: @user900324 We're going to need a lot more information than you've provided, starting with the call that resulted in the error and details of what (if anything) is in `/tmp`. If you can edit this to provide that, please flag this question for moderator review.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that the script uses a feature called temporary table in MySQL but MySQL is not properly configured to allow that feature on your (MySQL) server.

You need to talk with the system administrator of the server, explain the problem and let it get fixed.